# Get Image from Github repo using GraphQL [Javascript]

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

I want to get image from a `github` repository and show it in my website.
Say, I have a image in my `github-repo` called `banner.png`. I have been successful at getting the content of `README.md` file which is a plain text. But images are binary thus I don't know how to get them (or just a `url` to that image) to use in `img` tag. I've searched and the `blob` does have a `commitUrl` but I don't know what that is for. I've tried using as the `src` for `img` but it doesn't work. I've even tried visiting that `url` but it just give a `404` not found.

Answer (score -2):

If your repo is public, you can use a free hosting solution such as https://www.jsdelivr.com which can serve the file from Github (https://www.jsdelivr.com/features#gh) with the right content-type. You just have to build the url according to :

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/<user>/<repo>@<branch>/path/to/file.png
```

A few example :

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/bertrandmartel/newhaven-oled-dk51@master/img/newhaven-dk51.jpg
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/bertrandmartel/websocket-java@master/exemples/readme_images/clientSide.png
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/bertrandmartel/fritzing-parts@master/metec-braille-line-20-cell/metec-braille-line-20-cell.svg